# Seekbar in listview can not update its progress correctly

Tags: android, android-listview, seekbar

I'm trying to create a listview with BaseAdapter, where a new class ItemAdapter is created with extending the BaseAdapter. Each list_item in the listview may have a seekbar in it.

The listview is created in Mainactivity.

Since the seekbar's OnSeekBarChangeListener() will have to use some data member in Mainactivity, I want to "new" it in Mainactivity and set the listeners before adding it into the listview. 
By using a HashMap, the seekbar can be then transfered into the listview and be added to the layout.(By overriding the getView() method in ItemAdapter class, seekbar can be prgramably added)

The PROBLEM is:

I have two list_item on the top of listview, each of them has a seekbar. However, the first list_item's seekbar (seekbar1) can not be moved, while the second's (seekbar2) can be.

By printing some message, I found:

1) Each seekbar is "Enabled", if I print seekbar.isEnable() in seekbar.onProgressChanged()

2) However, by setting the target SDK to 16, it can be found that the view of seekbar1 is "Disabled", while the view of seekbar2 is "Normal".

3) The OnSeekBarChangeListener two seekbars seems to work normally.

4) By scrolling the listview such that the recycling mechnism of the listview can be triggered, the view of seekbar1 will change to "normal". However, it's still unmovable.

5) When moving seekbar2, the view of seekbar1 will also change to "Normal", but will change back to "Disabled" after that.

In order to fix this, I even tried to use

seekBar.setProgress(progress)  in  seekBar.onProgressChanged(...).

But it does not work.

Can anyone help me? THX

Comment: then make seekbar.setEnable(true) programatically while layout inflation

Comment: thanks for comment. Do you mean I should try seekbar.setEnable(true) when getView(...){} is called?
I have already tried this way, but this did not work...